# Push was rejected due to missing or corrupt local objects

Tags: git

I have a lfs local repo with its remote bitbucket. I work with Unity and Visual studio and my routine is assisted commit with visual studio.  My current commits are not allowed to be `push`-ed.
Git throws missing files errors but when I follow the path the files are there and ok.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: It won't help with your current issue, but make sure your components are up to date. Differing versions of Visual Studio have changed how they handle git and the operations for the most part have gotten better.

Comment: it's precisely just after visual studio updates that I usually got git errors. This time is also just after updating vs.

Comment: VS ultimately just parrots the underlying git call. Any git error, is git related....I now generally process the git commands from the commandline. With a better understanding of the process, it *generally* leads to less failures... IMHO GL

Comment: usually my git error from updating vs are credentials. (need to log into my bitbucket acount after that or it don't push, even by command line).

Comment: `git config --local --edit` and make sure your creds are represented in the local config such as  (multiple lines mind you) `[user]` next line tabbed in `name = ΩmegaMan` and 
`email = myEmailForThisOrigin@ΩmegaMan.com`.  I go between github and Azure devops and do that for all my local configs. `--global` is where the default lives if none are specified in the local.  Just a thought... Je travai pour vous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [seen here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/267120), your error should be like:

```sh
(missing) code.tar.gz (f2b4bf22bcb011fef16f80532247665d15edbb9051***)
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
hint: Your push was rejected due to missing or corrupt local objects.
hint: You can disable this check with: 'git config lfs.allowincompletepush true'
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.example.com:group/project.git'
```

Following [this issue](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2446#issuecomment-318367392), start with

```
 git lfs fetch --all
```

See if the error persists then.
If it does, try it from a fresh cloned repo (`git lfs clone my-repo`)

---

From [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238952/discussion-between-bsmall-and-vonc):

- `git lfs fetch --all` could not work, since what is missing was never pushed in the first place
- a new `git lfs clone`, followed by reporting the old repository local work did get added, committed and pushed successfully.

Comment: so git fetch --all ? I don't understand what is does. and re push just after that ?

Comment: git gives these errors after the fetch command "Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server" I really can't understand what is happening here because these object can not be on the server obviously because this is the first time I will push them (I suppose these errors are about the same missing files)

Comment: @bsmall That would be `git lfs fetch --all`, not `git fetch --all`

Comment: I did git lfs fetch --all and I get the errors "Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server". What do you mean by clone repo ? like I kill my current git local repo ?

Comment: @bsmall Yes, the other option is to clone the repository again, but in a separate local folder (not "killing" your current repository).

Comment: sorry I don't understand. what clone means here ? do I delete the initial repo after that ? what about the remote ?

Comment: @bsmall No need to delete anything. The idea is to try and [`git lfs clone`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-clone.1.ronn) your remote repository, to check if it has what was missing in the current local repo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238952/discussion-between-bsmall-and-vonc).